# Постройка графиков на qt, алгоритм

Tags: qt

Строю графики на qt с библиотекой qcustomplot. С ней разобрался и повторил примеры - работают.

По вифи принимаю данные с устройства и пишу в файл(данных может быть много, может мало). Данные идут с датчиков - одно целое число. Датчиков 15 - гироскопы.

Пишу в файл каждый пакет значений раз в 1с, в виде след строк(каждая строка это новые значения с датчиков, т.е. 1 строка это показания датчиков за 1с):

```
10,15,25,36,10,47,5,12
11,15,25,36,10,47,5,12
12,15,25,36,10,47,5,12
13,15,25,36,10,47,5,12
14,15,25,36,10,47,5,12
15,15,25,36,10,47,5,12
16,15,25,36,10,47,5,12
```

Далее, я открываю этот файл и читаю построчно , парсю строки и пишу данные в массив, строю график, обновляю его. Т.е. перед каждым обновление графика я читаю файл полностью.

Правильно мыслю? Как можно сделать проще?

Comment: Я правильно понял что вы каждый раз перечитываете одни и те же данные?

Comment: Да, читаю полностью файл и строю график.

Comment: ИМХО, разумнее читать с того места, где остановились в прошлый раз и добавлять новые данные на график

Comment: Думаю вам в этом помогут методы [`QFileDevice::pos`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#pos), [`QFileDevice::seek`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#seek) и [`QCPGraph::addData`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPGraph.html#a0bf98b1972286cfb7b1c4b7dd6ae2012)